# Android JSON retrieve objects from url

Tags: android, json

I have script return JSON like this

```
{"a":"something","b":"something"}
{"a":"something1","b":"something1"}
```

It's NDJSON response!
Now i am trying to retrieve it from android but i get null on jsonResult.
This is the code I use after fetching:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
```

I get null pointer exception on first line because jsonResult is null.
What is wrong?

This is how i fetch:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
```

Comment: Can you post your `jsonResult` ? You have this error because `jsonResult` is null

Comment: posted more code.. can you analyze what is wrong?

Comment: Maybe posting this method will help us understand a bit more `inputStreamToString`

Comment: org.apache.http.HttpResponse is deprecated. You should not use this code for a new project

Answer (score 0):

Check if result is null before using it

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(params[0]);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

if(result != null) {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
    JSONArray jsonMainNode = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
} else {
    //Do something
}
```

Now you have to check your request or the `inputStreamToString` method to know why you have a null response.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
 HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            String json = sb.toString();
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Comment: what is "is" ? how do I define it?

Comment: changed  HTTP.UTF_8 to "UTF_8" .. but still json is null

Comment: Does you request work ? Does it return someting ? You can test it using [curl](https://github.com/bagder/curl)

Comment: Yes with curl it is returning JSON as i mentioned in the first post. But from Android i can't get it. It's the newline delimited JSON, as i described. I feel your code is very close to solve this, but still not working..